# Trying to get the author, content and user who pinned a message?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to get the user who pinned a message, the author of the message and the message content.
this is what i have:

```js
client.on("channelPinsUpdate", message => {
    const pinEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Message Pinned")
    .setAuthor("PIN AUTHOR")
    .addField("Info",`Pin author: ${author}\nPinned by: ${member_who_pinned}\nPin: ${content}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    client.channels.cache.get("channel ID").send(pinEmbed);
});
```

I don't know how to get this info from the pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation, you can't get author, pinned member and content.
You can only use **channel** and **date** parameters.
Here the link to [documentation](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelPinsUpdate).

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you fetch it from the audit log.